# While transition the page after click, screen is going black

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

here is my code:
I using storyboards

```
 NewsDetailViewController *newsdetail=[[NewsDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
 newsdetail.modalTransitionStyle=UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
 [self presentModalViewController:newsdetail animated:YES];
```

I have a collectionview i fetched some datas from api and put them to the cells of collectionview. I want to get details of items that i clicked on cell but after click details doesn't work but black screen is coming.

here is my all output :

```
2013-06-17 14:20:30.288 xproject[7511:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/sezgindemir/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/67BC91AF-5091-4F39-A2BD-CA7E1DD0FEF0/xproject.app> (loaded)' with name 'NewsDetailViewController''
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1c99012 0x10d6e7e 0x1c98deb 0x236ef9 0xfb7e7 0xfbdc8 0xfbff8 0xfc232 0x107c25 0x3073a3 0x104ee3 0x105167 0x1051a7 0x4c3d 0x51c42f 0x52e182 0x52e394 0x10ea705 0x12893c 0x1289ac 0x10ea705 0x12893c 0x1289ac 0x2e21d3 0x1c61afe 0x1c61a3d 0x1c3f7c2 0x1c3ef44 0x1c3ee1b 0x1bf37e3 0x1bf3668 0x1affc 0x25ed 0x2515)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)
```

Comment: What do you mean screen is going back?

Comment: First check if your newsdetail view controller is loading i.e its not nil.

Comment: Check the target membership of the NewsDetailViewController.xib file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the xib for NewsDetailViewController in storyboard or separate xib?

If it is a separate xib, make sure your xib name is NewsDetailViewController.xib. Then it should work.

If the nib is in storyboard the 
first set the storyboardID of the xib to `NewsDetailViewController` and then use

```
NewsDetailViewController *newsdetail=[[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NewsDetailViewController"];
newsdetail.modalTransitionStyle=UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:newsdetail animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not loading view controller properly.

Try this code:

```
UIViewController *vc=[[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NewsDetail"];//you have to give it this name (or any) in the storyboard

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

Make sure you have a uinavigationController controlling self

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed to provide the `NibName`

Your code

```
NewsDetailViewController *newsdetail=[[NewsDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
```

It should be

```
NewsDetailViewController *newsdetail=[[NewsDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"YOUR_NIB_NAME" bundle:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this -
    NewsDetailViewController *news detail = [[NewsDetailViewController alloc] init];